# How to handle this issue - NoMethodError vs NoRecordFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

just wondering the best way to handle the following, as there seems to be conflicting information on the internet about this. My code started life like this..

```
@merchant = Merchant.find_by_name(params[:merchant])
@products = @merchant.products.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Now that works great, until you hit a url where the merchant won't exist i.e. `/merchants/thisonedontexist/` at which point I get the following error:

```
`undefined method `products' for nil:NilClass`
```

I understand why I am getting this error.

So then after a bit of research, I decided to change my code to the following with a BANG (!), which raises a NoRecordFound error so it never hits the next line, trouble is, I now get an ugly error:

```
@merchant = Merchant.find_by_name!(params[:merchant])
@products = @merchant.products.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Error is: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`

So after a bit more research, I did the following, and redirected these requests to a 404...

```
  def show
    @merchant = Merchant.find_by_name(params[:merchant])
    if !@merchant.nil?
      @products = @merchant.products.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    else
      redirect_to :status => 404
    end
  end
```

Which appears to work, but seems very clunky... What's the best practice here?

I'd like for it just to show a page with like `"Sorry no category exists"`.

p.s. I'm new to Rails, maybe there is a really n00b obvious answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the bang version is the best approach. A NoMethodError give me the idea you are not correctly handling the application workflow.

Also, using the bang version you can simplify your code.
In production, the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is rescued as 404. It means, when the error is raised, Rails will rescue the error and display the 404 error page with a 404 status code for you by default.

See the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L16).

You can simplify your code

```
def show
  @merchant = Merchant.find_by_name!(params[:merchant])
  @products = @merchant.products.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I do need the ".all" otherwise I get the following error: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Calculations::CALCULATIONS_OPTIONS

Comment: So Simone, are you saying that when I deploy this to a production server that this error will default to a 404 ? Is there any way to test this locally? ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MerchantsController#show

Couldn't find Merchant with name = xxx

Comment: Yes. You can even test it on your machine, but you need to run the production environment or disable the `consider all request as local` feature which automatically shows each error when you are running the app via localhost.

Comment: If you want to make it sure, create a functional test and use it to validate the feature.

Comment: How do I put into production locally? Sorry I am a newb :(. I know it's something like ENV=production. If this is the case, this is just another reason why Rails is awesome

Comment: Instead of `rails server`, run `rails server -e production`. But it might not be enough, I don't remember if the rescue will skip the `127.0.0.1` control. I encourage you to use functional or integration testing for this task.

Answer (score 0):

As @simone says, you could simplify your code to

```
def show
  @merchant = Merchant.find_by_name!(params[:merchant])
  @products = @merchant.products.all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Now, when the @merchant is not found, an exception is raised. And luckily rails offers an excellent solution to handles exceptions nicely.

Inside your controller (or your `ApplicationController` if you want to make it generic) you write

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :handle_not_found

def handle_not_found
  # either 
  flash[:error] = ... some appropriate error message ...
  redirect_to :root # or some relevant path
end
```

so inside that method you can do whatever you want to handle the exception as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

controller

```
  def show
    @merchant = Merchant.find_by_name(params[:merchant])
    @products = @merchant.products.all.paginate(:page => params[:page]) if @merchant
  end
```

in your view /show.html.erb

```
if @merchant
  ...
  ...your code here
else
  <div>No such merchant</div>
end
```

Comment: Sorry this is 'clunk-o-matic'